# Databrowser with move function

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a little databrowser, you can successfully create folders, they get created on the server and in the sql table 'folder', in this 'folder' table the userid is saved too.

Now i want to code my move function for moving files around folders, this function gets all folder names created by the user, and puts them into a  input form.

In my last query it doesnt gets the folderid, so it cant put the folder id into the imglinks table.

Hope you understand, and can help me. 
Thanks.

**move.php**

```
<form action="move.php" method="POST">
  <label>Move to:
    <select name="folders" size="5">
    <?php
    include "config.php";
    session_start();

    $uid = $_SESSION['username'];
    $dir = "uploads/" . $uid;
    $dir_inhalt = scandir($dir);
    $moveimg = $_GET['moveimg'];

    foreach($dir_inhalt as $folder){
        if($folder != "." && ($folder != "..")){

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM folder WHERE uid='$uid' AND foldername='$folder'";
            $folderresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $folderarray = mysqli_fetch_array($folders);
            $folderid = $folderarray['id'];

            echo $sql;

            if(is_dir($dir .'/'. $folder)) {
                echo "<option class='foldername' name='". $folderid ."'>$folder</option>";
            }
          }
        }
        ?>
        </select>
      </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Move it!">
    </form>

    <?php
        $move = "INSERT INTO imglinks (folderid) VALUES ('$folderid') WHERE id='". $moveimg ."'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $move);

    var_dump($move);
?>
```